# Assert zero jobs enqueued using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The `rspec-rails` gem [has some support](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/job-specs/job-spec) for testing `ActiveJob`.

Does it provide a way to **assert that zero jobs were enqueued?**

Rails provides a method called `assert_no_enqueued_jobs` but it's a little awkward to use in RSpec, because you have to `include ::ActiveJob::TestHelper`.

```rb
RSpec.describe BananaController, type: :controller do
  include ::ActiveJob::TestHelper
  describe "#create" do
    context "access denied" do
      it "does not enqueue any jobs" do
        # ...
        assert_no_enqueued_jobs
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: never tried this, but that documentation you linked has a `have_enqueued_job` matcher, what happens if you try `expect { ... }.not_to have_enqueued_job`?

Comment: I tried `expect { ... }.not_to have_enqueued_job` but it looks like that's saying "I expect the number of enqueued jobs to be any number other than one". I want to assert that exactly zero jobs were enqueued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.size).to eq(0)
```

Comment: Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapter/ClassMethods.html#method-i-queue_adapter and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/TestAdapter.html#method-i-enqueued_jobs

Comment: This will not work if another test enqueued a job before, this is a better solution: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher#expect-change